# Opencart sending Order's Options(size-colors) to Payment Provider(twocheckout)

Tags: opencart, 2checkout

I have searched and figured that if you use opencart and 2checkout together  , you can sometimes missing order while 2checkout is processing payment succesful. The reason is probably customer is not pushing FINALIZE button.

We can find product information in 2checkout control panel.But the problem we do not know which color or which size.

2checkout is keeping at their records if you send any info by "x_" tag so I think I need to create a form element which begins with "x_prodesc" which should be including color and size information. Do you guys know how to combine size and color information cause I could only get info from $product table.

I have plan to add :

  **<input type="hidden" name="x_prodetail_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $product['size']; ?>_<?php echo $product['color']; ?>" />**

Also I figure out that there is a tag from opencart "Option Info".Is there a way to let us write these details in Twocheckout Details records ?

Comment: Do you need details of unfinished orders? try my free extension: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&token=b7a573bf0dd807be9ba2c75dce41dd52&extension_id=27060

Comment: dear Mojtaba thanks for sharing info about your free extension but I am trying to figure our what and how to learn the system. Using more extensions making everything more complicated.But I will keep your extension in my mind for later use. Thanks for your coop.

Comment: you are welome.

Comment: Do you have any suggest about this tiny code in my form ?